# XCode - debugging application with signals

Tags: xcode, macos, signals

My application needs to do some processing once receiving "SIGUSR2".

So I use signal() to replace the system default signal-handler with mime.

While debugging in XCode, I signal the app with "kill -31 pid" in command line, and then the app is stopped at a line of code. After I make it continue, the app runs without calling the signal-handler of mime.

It seems that XCode eats up the signal itself...

How can I make it right while debugging in XCode?

Comment: It works good outside of XCode...

Comment: I find a way to deal with it. Pause the app, enter "handle SIGUSR2 nostop" in XCode GDB cmdline， and then Xcode won't eat up the signal and the app can process the target signal itself. Hoping there would be some smarter ways!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, was doing some stuff with code that had signals recently. Firstly you need to look into exactly how GDB handles signals. I'm not sure if it's in the documentation or not so dig around the net. From what I remember reading, GDB intercepts some of the signals so that the debugger can work properly. This would be why you app is not behaving properly.

I'm not authority on this by any means, but in the code I was looking at, the use of signals felt like it was the wrong thing to be doing. the iOS SDK has a whole range of features for handling interprocess communications, task sequencing and other stuff. Perhaps your code would benefit from a bit of R&D and redesign so you don't need signals.

Just a thought :-)

Comment: It works on Mac OS X, not an IOS application. It looks like a kind of daemons. The signal here is just used for test, but the problem is bothering.

Comment: Ok, check up on what the debugger disables. From what I was reading though, I don't think you can do much about it, or would want to as it's likely to make the debugger unstable as such. That's my understanding.